# I'm trying to make cubic yard calculator app for android and getting errors

Tags: android, calculator

This is my first attempt at coding. I'm trying to a make a cubic yard calculator for a friend of mine. I have the formula for the calculation, I tried some coding i saw in some youtube videos and now I'm stuck. I'm getting errors about string format and null pointer exception and something about decimals.
Here's what i got so far:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Length);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.width);
    EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.depth);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    int num3 = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
    int sum = num1 * num2 * num3 / 12 / 27;
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: i don't know what that is or how to get it, real noob here. sorry

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, it seems that you have calculated the variable `sum` without converting to double. This division by 12 and 27 will result in integer division and thus in information loss. The right way would be:

```
double sum = (double) num1 * num2 * num3 / 12 / 27;
```

And to convert a double to string you must use:

```
t1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

Comment: I'm still getting that java.lang.NullPointerException error. Is there a way for the code to activate only when the button is tapped, and how do i make the button usable only when the 3 fields are full?

Comment: ok i made a few changes like:       int num1 = 0;
        if (e1 != null) num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());

Comment: To make it activate only when the 3 fields are full you can put some "if" statements and if your requirements are not met when the user presses the button, a toast might show. E.g. if (textField empty) { Toast("Text Field should not be empty" }. I hope I helped!